# How can I get Selected columns from a CSV to my XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I need help to get out some specific/selected data/column from a CSV file to my XML file?
I found this code here but this take all columns to XML.

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"testbsp.csv");

        var xml = new XElement("Deltagere",
           lines.Select(line => new XElement("Deltager",
              line.Split(';')
                  .Select((column, index) => new XElement("Column" + index, column)))));
```

any idea? thanks!

Comment: Make a list (either columns index or column name).  Then use this : .Where((column, index) =>  Mylist.Cointains(index)).Select((column,index) => new XElement("Column" + index, column)))));

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library, you can easily convert CSV to xml file with few lines of code.

For a sample CSV file below, sample below shows how to produce xml file with Id, Name columns only

**Sample CSV:**

```
Id, Name, City
1, Tom, NY
2, Mark, NJ
3, Lou, FL
4, Smith, PA
5, Raj, DC
```

**Code:**

```
string csv = @"Id, Name, City
    1, Tom, NY
    2, Mark, NJ
    3, Lou, FL
    4, Smith, PA
    5, Raj, DC";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoCSVReader.LoadText(csv).WithFirstLineHeader()
    .WithField("Id")
    .WithField("Name")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoXmlWriter(sb)
        .Configure(c => c.RootName = "Emps")
        .Configure(c => c.NodeName = "Emp")
        )
    {
        w.Write(p);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
<Emps>
  <Emp>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Mark</Name>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Lou</Name>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Name>Smith</Name>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Name>Raj</Name>
  </Emp>
</Emps>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code :

For example if you have csv file like this :

```
string csv = @"Id, Name, City
    1, Tom, NY
    2, Mark, NJ
    3, Lou, FL
    4, Smith, PA
    5, Raj, DC";

// Read all lines
var lines[] = File.ReadAllLines(csv);

XElement xml = new XElement("Deltagere",
           // get second column of second line : Tom
           new XElement("NodeName", lines[1].Split(",").GetValue(1)),
           // get third column of fourth line : FL
           new XElement("NodeName2", lines[3].Split(",").GetValue(2))
);
```

You will get an XML file like this :

```
<Deltagere>
   <NodeName>Tom</NodeName>
   <NodeName2>FL</NodeName2>
</Deltagere>
```